# system.ExtrinsicFailed Token.NotExpendable

Tags: polkadot-js, substrate-node-template, polkadot, account, balances

I'm working on a project that involves setting up a shared pot account. Anyone can fund this account, and the owner has the ability to withdraw money from it. However, I'm encountering an `error: system.ExtrinsicFailed Token.NotExpendable.`[image]

This error occurs when I set the pot account to users like Charlie or Dave who have no initial funds. Strangely, if I set the pot account as Alice, Bob, or AliceStash, I can successfully withdraw the money. Could someone please help me understand why this is happening? Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your screenshot is `FundsUnavailable` instead of `NotExpendable`. Which one did you want to ask?

Comment: @AurevoirXavier Sorry for the confusion, Updated the image.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/e48e8368969d708abe7f200d345d8149ea3950ca/primitives/runtime/src/lib.rs#L685

This means your accounts(Charlie or Dave) doesn't have enough balance to use. Therefore, your withdrawal request has failed.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me when I wanted to hold only 1DOT in my wallet and delegate the rest. I changed to 5DOT and the error was gone